# Redirecting without change in URL in NGINX does not give desired results

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

If someone wants to go to the main website, he should be redirected to /getting-started

````
```location = / {
  return 301 /getting-started;
}```
````

but the /getting-started should bring the stuff from /basics like

`````
```location = /getting-started {
  rewrite "/getting-started" /basics/ last;
}````
`````

and the url should remain /getting-started

So all in all desired result is

**On going to root, the page should load stuff from /basics but the url should change to /getting-started. Now that also means if a user directly enters /getting-started, he will be served stuff from /basics while user will see the same url (/getting-started)**

Now I was able to do this using the code above.

**Problem is**
When the page is loaded, there are several links in it that should have path /basics/something.

But when I click the link, it become **/something  (NOT /basics/something)**. (as we are on /basics page even though the url remains /getting-started)
and so desired page does not load.

Its only happening when Im doing this redirection of root page. Please suggest how can it be fixed.

Comment: The links are probably using path-relative URLs (i.e. they do not begin with a `/`).